# Failing to auto align a text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, text-alignment

I'm trying to auto align a text, when the text is Arabic, the text starts from right, and if the text is English, the text starts from left. after searching the internet I found that i have to use `dir="auto"` in the tag, and `text-align: auto;` in the CSS file.
I worked with the `h1` tag but didn't work with the `a` tag.

**`The code:`**

```
import "./item.css";

const Item = ({ Links, title }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <h1 dir="auto" className="itemTitle">{title}</h1>
      {Links.map((link) => (
        <li key={link.name}>
          <a dir="auto" className="itemLinks"
            href={link.link}>
            {link.name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

**`The CSS file:`**

```
.itemTitle{
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
    text-align: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}

.itemLinks{
    color: gray;
    font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
    text-align: auto;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px; 
}
```

I don't know what i'm missing here, or it just don't work because i'm using map!! some help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that most likely you are missing that `a` is an inline element by default, so it will only be as wide as its content demands. And trying to "center" something, when it is exactly as wide as the element you want to center it _in_, is of course pointless.

Comment: Also, you can not have a headline element as child of an unordered list. The headline needs to go _into_ the list item.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a `<div dir="auto">` wrapper, everything inside it will have the `auto` text direction:

```
const Item = ({ Links, title }) => {
  return (
    <div dir="auto">
      <h1 className="itemTitle">{title}</h1>
      <ul>
        {Links.map((link) => (
          <li key={link.name}>
            <a className="itemLinks"
              href={link.link}>
              {link.name}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```css
[dir="auto"] > * {
  text-align: auto
}
```

In your case, the closest [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) element giving the achor element text-direction would be `<ul>`.
This means placing `dir="auto"` on `<ul>` would also work, you don't need a `<div>` wrapper. But, with the wrapper, you don't have to specify it in two places.

Side note: as someone noted in the comments, a `<h1>` tag is an invalid child of `<ul>` tag.